# Calculus 2 - $\int(\sqrt{72+36x^2})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have done this problem several times and this is the only answer i ever come to. My schools webwork gives me incorrect for my answer (answer is not simplified but it should be accepted in this format). Did i do this correctly?

Here is my work:
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{72+36x^2}\, dx&=\sqrt {36}\int \sqrt{2+x^2}\,dx\\
&=6\int \sqrt{2+x^2}\,dx\\
&=6\int \sqrt 2 \sec \theta \sqrt 2 \sec^2 \theta \, d\theta\\
&=12 \int sec^3 \theta d\theta=12\left[\frac{\tan \theta \sec \theta}2 +\frac 12 \int \sec\theta \, d\theta\right]\\
&=12\left[\frac{\tan\theta\sec\theta}2+\frac 12 \ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|\right]+C\\
&=6\tan \theta\sec\theta+6\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C\\
&=6\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}\right)\sec\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}\right)\\
&+6\ln \left|\sec\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}2\right)+\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}\right)\right|+C
\end{align}
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your link does not work, for me at least.

Comment: sorry I re-uploaded to imgur

Comment: To avoid downvotes and further issues (e.g. the question being deleted or the link being incomplete) [this might help you write mathematics in this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ricefieldboy I edited your post to make it more readable. Did I make any errors?

Comment: thanks alot, there was an error but i fixed it. hopefully someone can answer now

Comment: Looks correct to me, even though the answer is a bit hairy.

Comment: Try substituting $\tan\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sec\theta=\frac{\sqrt{2+x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ to get $3x\sqrt{2+x^2}+6\ln(\sqrt{2+x^2}+x)+C$

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your work is correct. However, at the end you are most likely asked to put this in a nicer form. The way to simplify $trig_1(trig_2^{-1}(\frac{a}{b}))$ is form a right triangle that fits your $trig^{-1}$ conditions and then compute $trig_1(angle)$.

As an example, simplifying $\tan{(\arctan{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}})}$ means forming a right triangle where the opposite side from an angle (we'll call $\theta$) is $x$ and the adjacent side from $\theta$ is $\sqrt{2}$. The hypotenuse of this triangle is obviously then $\sqrt{2+x^2}$. Therefore,

$$\tan{(\arctan{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}})}=\tan{\theta} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$$

The above could also be seen by recognizing that tangent and arctangent are inverse functions. Using this same triangle, we also have:

$$\sec{(\arctan{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}})} = \sec{\theta} = \frac{\sqrt{2+x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I'll leave you to simplify the rest.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

By the above diagram, we can show that
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=6(\tan \theta \sec \theta+\ln |\sec \theta+\tan \theta|)+c \\
&=6\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+2}}{\sqrt{2}}+\ln \left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right|\right)+c \\
&=3x \sqrt{x^{2}+2}+6 \ln \left|x+\sqrt{x^{2}+2}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$
:|D Wish it can help!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the complications associated with the trigonometric substitution, integrate directly instead
\begin{align}
I&=\int \sqrt{72+36x^2}\, dx=6\int \sqrt{2+x^2}\,dx\\
&\overset{ibp}=6x \sqrt{2+x^2}-I+12\int \frac1{\sqrt{2+x^2}}dx\\
&= 3x \sqrt{2+x^2}+6\sinh^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt2}+C
\end{align}